# Corona Writing a file

Tags: lua, save, coronasdk

I am creating a game and need to write the gamedata to a file. I have the game creating the file if its not there and reading the contents of the file (That I put in manually) but I can not get it to write to the file.

```
local path = system.pathForFile("gameData.gameData", system.DocumentsDirectory)
local myFile
defaultGameData = "It Worked"
if (path) then
   myFile = io.open(path, "r")
end

if(myFile) then
    print('file')
else
    myFile:close()
    --io.close(myFile) 
    myFile = io.open(path, 'w')
    myFile:write( "My Test" )
    io.close(myFile)
end

myFile = nil
```

That part works. i then move to the next scene and attempt to write something new

```
local saveData = "My app state data"
local path = system.pathForFile("gameData.gameData", system.DocumentsDirectory)
local myfile = io.open( path, "w" )
myfile:write( saveData )
io.close( myfile )
```

But get the error

mainMenu.lua:43: attempt to index local 'myfile' (a nil value)

I know the file is there in the sandbox, and this code was copied from the corona docs. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: `local myfile, err = io.open( path, "w" )` and then `print(err)` see what error you are getting.

Comment: Permission denied. So the file was created by the app. This error is happening in the simulator. I havent tested on the phone yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I opened the file to read to see if the file exists. I forgot to close it again before I reopened it in the if statement if the file did exist. I only closed it if it didnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

here are two functions I am using

```
function SaveTable(t, filename)
    local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open(path, "w")
    if file then
        local contents = JSON.encode(t)
        file:write( contents )
        io.close( file )
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end



function LoadTable(filename, dir)
    if (dir == nil) then
        dir = system.DocumentsDirectory;
    end

    local path = system.pathForFile( filename, dir)
    local contents = ""
    local myTable = {}
    local file = io.open( path, "r" )
    if file then
         -- read all contents of file into a string
         local contents = file:read( "*a" )
         myTable = JSON.decode(contents);
         io.close( file )
         return myTable 
    end
    return nil
end
```

Usage:

```
local t = {
    text = "Sometext",
    v = 23
};

SaveTable(t, "filename.json");

local u = LoadTable("filename.json");
print(u.text);
print(u.v);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to the mistake in your code line:

```
myFile:close()
```

So either comment the line as:

```
--myFile:close()
```

Or do as below (only if you need):

```
myFile = io.open(path, 'w')
myFile:close()
```

Keep Coding............. :)

Comment: I am closing the file because I opened it before. Then I am reopening it in "w" mode. Do I not need to close the file after I opened it as "r" to open as "w"

Comment: You are writing 'file:close()' inside the condition--> where there is no such file. So either you have to create a file before closing, or just avoid that closing... :)